# What happens if I pair a 5.0 bluetooth device with a 4.2 bluetooth one, about power consumption?

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth 5.0 compliant devices require less power to work than Bluetooth 4.2, which suggests portable devices using Bluetooth 5.0 connections should last longer on the same charge.

If I pair a 5.0 device to a 4.2 one, will the 5.0 device consume more power than if it was paired to another 5.0 one? I mean, does the device with Bluetooth 5.0 emulate a 4.2 version to pair with another 4.2 one, thus, consuming more power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If a Bluetooth device can't use the 5.0 protocols, and has to drop back to older protocols, that connection [using older rules will use more power](https://www.howtogeek.com/343718/whats-different-in-bluetooth-5.0/).